# Mobile App Indexing without having a WebApp

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, seo, android-app-indexing

I have a flutter App already for iOS /Android. I don't have a webapp, but I do have a website. SO out product is mobile first, and just have a website for blogs/a bit of content etc.

Also, I already have deep links/Universal links enabled for the app. I am wondering : Is it possible to enable app indexing for the App without web app?

Comment: You already tagged your question with `[android-app-indexing]`, which is described as "App indexing allows us to enable Google to crawl through an android app's content and present it to users through Google Search results." Did you try it already? https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing

Comment: Yeah, I already tried, but doen't seem to work. I am guessing that I don't have a webapp . That's why